# Facebook iframe like button not working

Tags: php, javascript, html, facebook, facebook-like

my facebook iframe like button is working offline but not online on the server..this is the code used:

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?app_id=125925834166578&amp;href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FBaradei.Presidency&amp;send=false&amp;layout=button_count&amp;width=450&amp;show_faces=true&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;font&amp;height=21" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:450px; height:21px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

And this is the webpage in which the like button at the bottom of the page isn't working http://www.ali_lsheikh.0fees.net/baradei.html

And here is it embeded in the facebook page
http://www.facebook.com/Baradei.Presidency?sk=app_103822229704881

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to replace the development app ID with your production app ID.